# return response only if it is from mobile phone

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, cordova, extjs, phonegap

We are developing a mobile application with phonegap, extjs and backend is .net code. Now i want to be sure that every request which is hitting .net code is from mobile Application. If it is from any other source we should not return any response.
Please can any one tell how to check if the request is from mobile app/mobile browser?

Comment: May be you can send request param .. like.. `is_from_mobile = "Y"` or something?

Comment: Use a authentication header in request.

Comment: Please elaborate on your use case. Every HTTP request can be sniffed and spoofed, so every device can tell you whatever it wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can check User Agent. That gives you idea about what browser type it is (iphone, chrome, etc)

Refer the link:
https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/

Answer (score 0):

You can check Like this :

```
  if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|pocket|psp|kindle|avantgo|blazer|midori|Tablet|Palm|maemo|plucker|phone|BlackBerry|symbian|IEMobile|mobile|ZuneWP7|Windows Phone|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
    {
     alert("App Open in Mobile");
    }
     else{
      alert("App Open in Other Source");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Extjs, you can handle it with framework code without using js userAgent regex:

```
if (Ext.os.is.Android || Ext.os.is.iOS) {
    // ... mobile
}else{
   // ... not mobile
}
```

[You can read the documentation about Ext.os here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.os.html#method-is)

Comment: i have to check this in the .net code.so pls give me .net code